# Which inliers is the RANSAC Algorithm using in cv2.FindHomography to find the homography matrix?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, homography, ransac

1) How is the RANSAC algorithm in OpenCV **choosing an inlier over an outlier**? I am presuming it calculates some total least square matching between the matched keypoints.

2)  I am fully aware that apart from the H matrix, the cv2.FindHomography also outputs the mask. And from this mask a matched keypoint which is a *1 is considered an inlier* whilst a *0 is considered an outlier*. But **which inliers is the RANSAC algorithm choosing to find the final H homography** outputted by cv2.FindHomography? Is it considering all of them to find the H matrix?

The [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html) is not explaining these two questions properly.

Comment: I am pretty sure the output parameter "mask" directly tells you which points are inliers and which points are outliers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [ransacReprojThreshold](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#findhomography) argument in the `findHomography` docs describes inliers vs outliers:

[image]

For 1), RANSAC computes the error (vector norm) between the observed projection, `dstPoint_i`, and the projection of `srcPoint_i` computed with a candidate homography, `H`. Then it just does a simple threshold check. The user can set the **ransacReprojThreshold** to whatever value you find that works best for your data. If you're in pixel coordinates, you just set the maximum error in pixel distance for a point to be considered an inlier. Anything with greater error is considered an outlier.

For 2), the RANSAC algorithm will simply choose the H matrix that maximizes the number of inliers based on the threshold you set. So the mask it returns to you is the is the set with the greatest number of inliers.

Does that make sense? It doesn't look like it gives you a ton of options in terms of random sample sizes, number of iterations, etc. [Here's the source](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4c86fc13cb8f272ac750ea03c90e6c9d8a855384/modules/calib3d/src/ptsetreg.cpp#L76), if you're interested.

Comment: Thank for your reply @doggie_breath The thing I cannot understand is the part of h. Isn't H supposed to be established from the inliers themselves? In that given equation what is the initial value of the H matrix?

Comment: @CharlesB, sure thing. For RANSAC, you choose a random subset from your src/dest points and compute H directly from that sample - as from [this method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/494238/how-to-compute-homography-matrix-h-from-corresponding-points-2d-2d-planar-homog). That H is used to compute the projection error of all the points in your set, and inliers are determined using the equation above. Then you just iterate on that sample/check and take the H with the maximum number of inliers. Does that make sense? This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BpOKB3OzQBQ) might help.